# Playing sound on right or left Speaker on MouseOver

Tags: python, pygame, onmouseover

I am trying to make small program in python, using PyQt5.
The program will as have two buttons, and a label in the middle. When the mouse goes over the label, I want to call a def, in order to change the button's color and play a sound from specific speaker (left or right)

I tried pygame, following some posts, but nothing. The sound is playing in both channels.

```
import time
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0) # argument must be int
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
print('OkkK')

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('Aloe Blacc - Wake Me Up.wav')
channel2.play(soundObj)
soundObj.set_volume(0.2)

time.sleep(6) # wait and let the sound play for 6 second
soundObj.stop()
```

Is there a way to fix this and choose the left-right speaker?

Also, is there a way to call a def, On Mouse Over a label?

Comment: we use backticks (`\``) for code blocks, not apostrophes (`'`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I be able to pan a sound in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631247/how-would-i-be-able-to-pan-a-sound-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `pygame` in general, prefer calling `pygame.init()` to initialise all of the `pygame` modules instead of typing separately `pygame.` *`module`* `.init()`. It will save you time and lines of code.

---

Then, to play a sound file in `pygame`, I generaly use [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) to get the file, then I call the `play()` function of the sound object.

So the following imports a sound file, then plays and pans it according to the mouse **X** position

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() # init all the modules

sound = pygame.sound.Sound('Aloe Blacc - Wake Me Up.wav')) # import the sound file

sound_played = False
# sound has not been played, so calling set_volume() will return an error

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) # make a screen

running = True
while running: # main loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # play the sound file
            channel = sound.play()
            sound_played = True
            # start setting the volume now, from this moment where channel is defined

    # calculate the pan
    pan = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] / pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()[0]
    left = pan
    right = 1 - pan

    # pan the sound if the sound has been started to play
    if sound_played:
        channel.set_volume(left, right)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: channel.set_volume(left, right)
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined

Should I add:  'channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)'  ???

Comment: Sorry, I edit my answer. I forgot to manage the fact that the program don't need to set the volume if the sound hasn't been played.